# goMap with MarkerClusterer does not take any effect on the current map

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm using the jQuery Google Maps v3 [plugin](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/), I want to add the MarkerClusterer with the goMap plugin, however I have this what it was intended to do:

```
$('#world-map').goMap(
{
    markers: mapMarkers,
    zoom: 2,
    icon: 'http://localhost/eproj/white-marker.png',
    streetViewControl: true,
});

$.goMap.ready(function()
{
    var markers = [];
    for (var i in $.goMap.markers)
    {
        var temp = $($.goMap.mapId).data($.goMap.markers[i]);
        markers.push(temp);
    }
    var markerclusterer = new MarkerClusterer($.goMap.map, markers, clustererOpts);
});
```

When viewing the map (currently has 35 markers) I don't see anything being taken into effect, except all the markers are being plotted. In Firebug I do not see any errors being logged, so I have no complete idea why this isn't working with goMap.

Anyone? Not even a simple solution?

EDIT: I can't put it on jsFiddle, seems to messes up with adding JS resources into jsFiddle.

This the `mapMarkers` variable:

```
[{"id":"9073a1977c8d5d6d7eb1666d03af4a66","address":"3  Essex St,  Jersey City,  Hudson,  United States"},{"id":"f63f77a0b2d0986f1f0e94bde07ff8ef","address":"96  Vesey St,  New York,  New York,  United States"},{"id":"57d5cb180425670f3e9c7b6e62fb88ac","address":"38  E Broadway,  Manhattan,  New York,  United States"},{"id":"bb464b47ca54a23edc3dee4a5f4299ad","address":"322  Tait Ave,  Sanger,  California,  United States"},{"id":"980f9d1e9e466d988f4851117a268e25","address":"1495  Morton Ave,  Parsons,  Kansas,  United States"},{"id":"389888acd972d01783547837841d5294","address":"160  N Washington St,  Clinton,  Missouri,  United States"}]
```

The markers are very close to each other, on the map zoom of 1, even though there's no marker clusterer taking effect.

Comment: Any chance of a working example / jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can you show me the mapMarkers variable definition?

Comment: are you still facing any problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[NEWLY EDITED]**

The simpliest workaround for this problem is by hack the `jquery.gomap-1.3.2.js` source code like below:

*add a markerCreated property on myOptions variable in the init function*

*Before*

```
var myOptions = {
  ....
  scrollwheel:          opts.scrollwheel,
  zoom:                 opts.zoom
};
```

***After***

```
var myOptions = {
  ....
  scrollwheel:          opts.scrollwheel,
  zoom:                 opts.zoom,
  markerCreated:        opts.markerCreated //patched here
};
```

*Change and add method on createMarker function:*

*Before*

```
createMarker: function(marker) {
  ....
  options.position = marker.position ? marker.position : new   google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);

  var cmarker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
  if (marker.html) {
  ....
},
```

***After***

```
createMarker: function(marker) {
  ....
  options.position = marker.position ? marker.position : new   google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);

  var goMap = this; //patched here
  var cmarker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
  if(goMap.opts.markerCreated) goMap.opts.markerCreated(cmarker); //patched here
  if (marker.html) {
  ....
},
```

And then in your own code change from:

```
$('#world-map').goMap(
{
    markers: mapMarkers,
    zoom: 2,
    icon: 'http://localhost/eproj/white-marker.png',
    streetViewControl: true,
});
```

to:

```
$(function() {

    var markerclusterer;
    var markers = [];
    var mapMarkers = [{"id":"9073a1977c8d5d6d7eb1666d03af4a66","address":"3  Essex St,  Jersey City,  Hudson,  United States"},
        {"id":"f63f77a0b2d0986f1f0e94bde07ff8ef","address":"96  Vesey St,  New York,  New York,  United States"},
        {"id":"57d5cb180425670f3e9c7b6e62fb88ac","address":"38  E Broadway,  Manhattan,  New York,  United States"},
        {"id":"bb464b47ca54a23edc3dee4a5f4299ad","address":"322  Tait Ave,  Sanger,  California,  United States"},
        {"id":"980f9d1e9e466d988f4851117a268e25","address":"1495  Morton Ave,  Parsons,  Kansas,  United States"},
        {"id":"389888acd972d01783547837841d5294","address":"160  N Washington St,  Clinton,  Missouri,  United States"}
    ];
    $("#map").goMap({
        markerCreated: function(marker) {
            markers.push(marker);
            //updated solution for slow MarkerClusterer loading
            if(markers.length == mapMarkers.length) {
                new MarkerClusterer($.goMap.map, markers);
            }
            //prev solution
            //if(!markerclusterer) markerclusterer = new MarkerClusterer($.goMap.map, markers);
            //markerclusterer.addMarker(marker);
        },
        markers: mapMarkers
    });
});
```

Remove the `$.goMap.ready` part

Please let me now if this hack work/not
Thanks

[EDITED]

I think this because when MarkerCluster is being created it doesn't passed with proper markers object parameter.
This because your mapMarkers variable need to be geocoded first before it created a marker object, meanwhile in your code you force to create a MarkerCluster before the markers porperly geocoded (return a marker object with position properties)

Believe me when you substitute your mapMarkers variable to objects of marker (I mean with already known positions) then you can see the cluster display properly
try this:

```
[{ 
    latitude: 40.713094,
    longitude: -74.033904,
    id: 'test1',
    title: 'marker title 1'
},{
    latitude: 40.712638,
    longitude: -74.03429,
    id: 'test2',
    title: 'marker title 2'
}]
```

[OLD]
Maybe this help:

[goMap Markercluster Soluton](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/solutions/markerclusterer.html)

Sorry can't write more simple solution then this ;)

Hint: Try to look the page source

Comment: Ah... so they all have to be geocoded into latitude/longitude..? Is there not a solution to make the addresses work for marker clusterer somehow?

Comment: Yup. This is can be done by doing some hack. Please see my updated answer for the hack hint.

Comment: It should be `this.opts` instead of `goMap.opts`, however it didn't seem to work, nothing was logged into Firebug. The markers are being plotted as usual, nothing is being taken into effect.

Comment: I already fixing up my answer. And you can check the working solution at http://enggon.com/so/markerclusterer.html

Comment: Your updated version works, however it plots quite slow, it's still plausible but could this be improved?

Comment: Try the updated answer for this. But if found nothing change in the speed. I bet this is because of the slow response on geocoding process from google map geocoding service.